# Make the selected RadioButton in a RadioButtonList unclickable but not disabled

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.Net page with several RadioButtonList controls on it.

I want to display this page in a read-only format, but I would like the selected radiobutton in each RadioButtonList to appear "normal" i.e not look disabled but not allow RadioButton to be clickable as I don't want the value to be modifyable.

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but my googling is failing me at the moment...

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's going to be VERY confusing for your users: when it comes to UI, if it looks normal it *really should* act normal. The average Joe will just assume something's wrong with the page.

Comment: @Alex - Indeed, this goes against the grain with me as well but in this case the UI needs to look a very specific way for a small group of users.

Comment: I see. I'm pretty sure they will complain anyway at some point, but if they want it like this by all means let them have it. Don't forget to ask more cash to revert things back to 'standard' when it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about overlaying a div on top of radio buttons container div with maximum z-index  and alpha set to max so that it will appear transparent. This makes radio buttons unclickable

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/chintupawan/ztT5j/

Comment: This is perhaps even more pretty, as the elements then don't respond to a click (which a false return or preventDefault still have). Only tricky thing is positioning.

Comment: Thanks to @Dominic Green as well for posting the same kind of solution a bit earlier. I found the jsfiddle Pavan provided to work straight out of the box for me - thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

To stop the button from also not beeing clickable you can use a div to overlay over them.

http://jsfiddle.net/heXQf/

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>           
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="rdo"/> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="rdo"/> Female
     </div>
</form> 

form{width:300px;position:relative;}
.block{width:100px;display:block;height:100px;position:absolute;top:0;}


    $('#rdo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: nice one, as this stops all interaction, including the apparent response from a click

Comment: I think there is also a way in css if you dont mind not support ie6 .radio[disabled] {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery:

```
$('.class-of-radio-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/Gkp2Z/

Comment: Even better would be something like `$('.radio').attr("tabIndex",-1).click(...`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("input[type!='radio'], select, textarea ").attr('disabled',true);
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: `.attr('readonly',true)` might be better for the text fields, if the OP wants them to look "normal" too.